# How to pass config options to a global node package?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a CLI (using Commander) node module with the following directory structure

```
|--myProject
|  |--lib
   |  |--config.js
   |  |--main.js
```

The config file takes the form

```
var config = {};

config.host = 'localhost';
config.user = 'admin';
config.password = 'password';
config.database = 'doge';

module.exports = config;
```

and then in `main.js` I `require` the config file and set things up accordingly.

It works great for me locally but I'd love to publish it to `npm`, having never published a package (and I think it would eventually be useful for others). I just don't know how I would then set the config variables.

Since it's a CLI, I set the following in `package.json` so that ideally it can be run from anywhere by just using `myProject --whateverOptions`

```
"preferGlobal": "true",
"bin": {
  "myProject" : "lib/main.js"
}
```

Say I publish it, and then someone comes along and runs `npm install -g myProject`. They could go to their global `node_modules` directory, into `myProject/lib` and add their own `config.js`.

I have two issues with this approach though

1. It seems overly messy for anyone that wants to use my package
2. If I update the package, and they then `npm update` will their `config.js` be erased?

Comment: I have an app like this. First, the config file is blank. The app tries to detect if there is property in it, say, `config.password`. If it's not there, it prompts the user for all the config properties, then writes a new config file.